# Excel Index/Vlookup - Search Column for ABSOLUTE closest or exact value and highlight

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, vlookup

I'm new to coding in Excel, so I apologize in advance if this sounds like something I should all ready know. VERY new!

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

In, let's say, Cell A1 I have a numerical value. I want to search all of the values in Column D (none repeating/duplicate), and find the closest absolute value (be it exact, lesser than or greater than the value in A1). After the closest has been identified, I would like to have the cell Highlighted. How do I accomplish this using the Index Command.

After this was figured, I figured I can just run an incrementing count loop (like your typical Count++ used in C++) to do the same process over and over for A2, A3, A4, etc... Any feedback/validation that the incrementing count loop would work too.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts to this.  First in cell **B1** enter the *array formula:*

```
=INDEX(D:D,MATCH(MIN(ABS(D:D-A1)),ABS(D:D-A1),0))
```

[image]

This first part gets the nearest value *(that value for which the absolute value of the difference is smallest)*.

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

For the second part, click on cell **D1** and assign conditional formatting with the FormulaIs Option:

```
=D1=$B$1
```

[image]

Then copy **D1**'s format down the column.

The proper cell in column **D** will now be formatted.